# mCustomScrollbar scrolling on wrapper but not scrolling on ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a weird bug, i am using select2 to style my select elements and i applied the mCustomScrollbar plugin to make a nice scroll, but the problem is that when i apply mCustomScrollbar and i put my mouse on the wrapper just is scrolling fine but when i put the mouse over my ul list with elements is not scrolling any more.

All the ideas are welcome

i did a screenshot to be more clear
http://postimg.org/image/wgyvdc05n/

on the screenshot where is ul from left is not scrolling, the wrapper is available on the scroll element and around 20px from the scroll in this area is scrolling but not on ul element.

i tried to make it in jsfiddle but couldn't manage to get the same result

**my select**

```
    <select id="login" name="login" class="_il_select_styled_">
        <option value="" selected="">Select account</option>
        <option value="2088722430">2088722430 | USD | 68993498.48</option>
        <option value="2088722865">2088722865 | USD | 7234.0</option>
        <option value="2088722882">2088722882 | USD | 0.0</option>
        <option value="2088722883">2088722883 | USD | 110.0</option>
        <option value="2088722884">2088722884 | USD | 0.0</option>
    </select>
```

**First is applying the select2 plugin after that is applying mCustomScrollbar**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so long time there is no fix for this. Switch to selectize.js and everything will work fine with mCustomScrollbar